# accessing OCaml records

Tags: ocaml, record

How can I use some OCaml record that I've defined in some other file? Say for example that I have the file a.ml in which I define the r record:

```
type r = {
  i: int;
  j: int;
};
```

and a file b.ml in which I want to use the r record. Something like this:

`let s = {i = 12; j = 15;}` clearly doesn't work - I know it has something to do with accessing the module in which the record is defined, but I've yet to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The types and values defined in a.ml live in the module A. So you need to either `open A` (thereby bringing all definitions from A into scope) or refer to `i` and `j` as `A.i` and `A.j` respectively.

Comment: Ah, hmm, ok ... for me it wasn't working this way because I was doing something like: a.ml would hold the record definition, a.mli wouldn't hold anything related to that record and I was trying to access the record from b.ml. How would one go with such a case - define the record in the interface ? Either ways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, type definitions that are meant to be used from other files are part of the interface, so they need to be in the mli file if there is one.